# Translate iptables rule to UFW

Tags: 22.04, iptables, firewall, ufw

I need to translate these rules:

```
iptables -A firewall -p udp –dest 239.250.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A firewall -p igmp –dest 239.250.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
```

To UFW rules. Don't know how to set -A -dest -j. I have tried this rules but doesn't work.

```
sudo ufw allow proto udp to 239.250.0.0/16
```

How should be the command for UFW?

Comment: It adds rules to `Chain ufw-user-input`. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Is it some forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of search and asking around, I was advised to switch from UFW to nftables. And then I used `iptables-translate` command to create the rules that I needed, so it was something like:

```
iptables-translate -A firewall -p igmp --destination 239.250.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
```

And I was able to solve the issue like that...